# EXCEL import: share point calculated field source columns are blank while others can see data in them

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, excel, import, data-connection

I understand that exporting a share point List view with calculated column will pull the source columns for that calculated column to excel even if they are not in the view. my issue is there is no data under the source Columns while others can open the excel and they saw the source columns fields have data in them. can someone explain this behavior?

is there a setting in excel makes source columns of a calculated column to have data in them even if they are not in the view? or is the query?

Update!!:

Here is the Issue.
I have a view that have a calculated field named x+y+z only like image below:

[image: Sharepoint view]

if I import this view into excel it will show up like this
[image: Excel View without data]
some users have the same excel import (view) with x y z columns having data in them. 
[image: Excel view with data]

I suspect it is an excel issue/setting rather than sharepoint issue. but I was hoping for someone who can shed some light and explain the behavior.

Comment: what did you mean by "there is no data under the source Columns while others can open the excel and they saw the source columns fields have data in them"? To understand this issue better, you can provide some screenshots about your issue.

Comment: I have added more context.. thank you!